# How to pass a parameter in SQL statement in Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I have this code snippet which will delete all rows in the `user_interests` table. I have a parameter of `int id` which is user id. I want to pass this parameter to my SQL statement. I have tried using `".... user_id = @id"` but it wont work when I run it on Postman. I also tried using static value for is `"... user_id = 1"` and it is working fine.

```
public boolean deleteInterest(int id) {
        boolean isDeleted = false;
        String sql = "DELETE FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = @id" ;
        
        if(userRepository.findById(id) != null) {
            dbTemplate.execute(sql);
            isDeleted = true;
        }
        
        return isDeleted;
    }
```

How can I pass the id parameter to my sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the I'd parameter like below as this is very basic.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = " + id
```

This will work fine but it has a risk of SQL injection so you should set the parameters using prepared statements.

Comment: Please read full answer as I have clearly mentioned there

Comment: thank you, this will be our last resort if we will not be able to fix the issue since this is only for school project. I tried and it works, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but have a look at prepared statements in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = '"+parameterName+"'";
```

You can pass the parameter in sql query like this